# How to get around the user initialization?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a question regarding Windows Server 2008 R2 users. When a new user logs on for the first time, he this little window in the top left corner while his account is initialized for a few minutes.

Is it possible to do this initialization without having the user to log in? I am creating users from a batch process and would like to have them initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about profile creation - so its more to do with the client than the server.

Are you using roaming profiles? If so, you just need to log them onto a domain machine of the same operating system. If not, then you need to log them onto their specific machine and there's no way round that.

You could probably find some way of scripting / automating this, but it really depends on how exactly you're creating the users and what you're doing with passwords etc.

Edit: As you're on a terminal server, you may be able to abuse some kind of stress testing. Here's the kind of thing I'm thinking of:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/erenturk/archive/2011/01/19/how-to-stress-test-terminal-services-with-windows-powershell.aspx

I want to **very** clear, however, that I don't endorse or recommend this. I'm answering the question you've asked - but I really think the question itself is flawed. It's by design that the first logon creates the profile, and it's been this way for many years with no indication that it's due to change. You should be concentrating on sorting out your logon times - unless you're running some specific application with a known issue I guess.

Comment: Can this logon be automated by a script?

Comment: What OS are the users using?

Comment: They are logging on to a Windows Server 2008 R2 using Remote Desktop.

Comment: I've got to admit - I think this is going to be a struggle. I mean, I've never seen anyone need to do this before. Serious question - is there a specific reason it takes so long to log in? It should be pretty quick - certainly acceptable for a first user logon. Also, is this server JUST a TS server?

Comment: Yes, its just a Terminal Server.

Answer (score 0):

I would give User State Migration Tool 4 a chance. You might be able to use that to migrate new profiles from a template profile.